# Adding a datePicker in FullCalendar / custom button click

Tags: datepicker, fullcalendar

I added a datePicker (http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/) right below the FullCalendar (http://fullcalendar.io) page.

how can i attach this date picker to a custom button on the header of the fullcallendar and when the button is pressed the datepicker will show up?

thanks

UPDATE: added code

EDIT: code updated

the code i written so far is:
JS:

```
$(function () { 
        //...some code.....
            //fullcalendar 
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                //...options
                header: {
                    left: 'title today',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'prevMonth prev myCustomButton  next nextMonth'
                },
                customButtons: {
                    myCustomButton: {
                        text: ' ',
                        click: function () {
        $('#date').DatePicker({
            flat: true,
            date: currentDate,
            current: currentDate,
            calendars: 2,
            starts: 1,
            onChange: function (formated, dates) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', formated);
               }
        });
                 }
                    },
                    //...other buttons
                },
                 //....other options....
            });//fullcalendar
         });//$
```

ASP:

```
        <div>
            <div id='calendar'></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p id="date"></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you at least provide some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: updated the question with code

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at fullcalendar custom buttons?

[customButtons](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/customButtons) documentation

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$(function () { 
    //... some code....
    // for the date picker 
    $('#date').DatePicker({
        flat: true,
        date: currentDate,
        current: currentDate,
        calendars: 2,
        starts: 1,
        onChange: function (formated, dates) {
            //when user clicks the date it scrols back up
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', formated);
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            $('#date').DatePickerHide();
        }
    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title today',
            center: '',
            right: 'prevMonth prev myCustomButton  next nextMonth'
        },
        customButtons: {
           myCustomButton: {
               text: ' ',
               click: function () {
                   //it scrolls to the position of the datepicker
                   $('body,html').animate({
                       scrollTop: $(document).height()
                   }, 1000);
                   $('#date').DatePickerShow();
               }
           },
             //...other buttons
        },
             //....other options....
    });//fullcalendar
});//$
```

Comment: I am using custom buttons, updated the queston with code. The problem is that when i put the $('date')...... inside the custom button the date picker does not open at all.

Comment: @athskar You are scrolling down the page to the datepicker but aren't doing anything to show it. I had a look at the documentation and it states you can just call show or hide. I have updated my answer to use your code and added the calls to to show and hide.

Comment: @athskar When you call the invocation code if it is displayed by default just hide it after it's initialised. Then you can show/hide it as above.

Comment: It is already shown right below the calendar, i did the scroling thing cause we needed to have the calendar asap in the screen. 
updated the code and made some changes to disable the scrolling. but still the calendar is shown below the calendar. how can i set the position right below the custom button?

Comment: I think I have misunderstood what you were originally trying to achieve. When you said how can you attach it to the button and you had code to scroll to it I thought you wanted it displayed below the calendar and then you wanted to show/hide it when you pressed the button. To have it display below the button I personally would use Javascript or Jquery to append the datepicker div where you want in your document ready function.

Comment: maybe my question wasn't clear, thanks anyway. If you can provide some code it would be nice. how do i know where to append the datepicker div?

Comment: Try appending it right below the button element. Check out the two examples at the bottom of the datepicker site http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/ You would then just close it when the onChange event is triggered. It looks like it will be reasonably straight forward, I won't be home until late tonight but I can give it a try when I get home.

Comment: @oxwilder, thanks for the edit. Do you think referencing the latest documentation is useful? This was a solution for V3, we might be better referencing that specific version.

Comment: @AllyMurray Right you are, although in trying to revise the link to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/customButtons I learned that edits need to be more than six chars. So maybe future readers will find the link here.

Answer (score 4):

I'm trying to do the same thing : adding jquery datepicker to fullcalendar custom button.
Does anyone know how to do this?

The best I can do is declaring both, one on top of the other, and linking datepicker select event to fullcalendar update view event (see sample below). 
It works fine but what I want is declaring datepicker inside fullcalendar custom button rather than outhere in a div.

Thanks for your feedbacks!

Sample of what I'm doing :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({

        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: " ",
        dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', dateText);
        },

    });


    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        timezone : 'local',
        height:750,
        theme: true,
        businessHours: true,
        editable: true,

        customButtons: {
            datePickerButton: {
                themeIcon:'circle-triangle-s',
                click: function () {
                    $('#datepicker').datepicker("show");

                }
            }
        },

        // header
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today datePickerButton',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
    });
 });

(...) 

<p>Date <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

LATER:

Thanks to : [This github fullcalendar issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3233) I've been able to had a datepicker to fullcalendar header custom button.

This is how to proceed :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        timezone : 'local',
        height:750,
        theme: true,
        businessHours: true,
        editable: true,

        customButtons: {
            datePickerButton: {
                themeIcon:'circle-triangle-s',
                click: function () {


                    var $btnCustom = $('.fc-datePickerButton-button'); // name of custom  button in the generated code
                    $btnCustom.after('<input type="hidden" id="hiddenDate" class="datepicker"/>');

                    $("#hiddenDate").datepicker({
                        showOn: "button",

                        dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
                        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', dateText);
                        },
                    });

                    var $btnDatepicker = $(".ui-datepicker-trigger"); // name of the generated datepicker UI 
                    //Below are required for manipulating dynamically created datepicker on custom button click
                    $("#hiddenDate").show().focus().hide();
                    $btnDatepicker.trigger("click"); //dynamically generated button for datepicker when clicked on input textbox
                    $btnDatepicker.hide();
                    $btnDatepicker.remove();
                    $("input.datepicker").not(":first").remove();//dynamically appended every time on custom button click

                }
            }
        },

        // header
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today datePickerButton',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my basic no jQuery solution with **[Fullcalendar 4](https://fullcalendar.io/)** and **[Pikaday](https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday)**

```js
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    
    // Initialize fullcalendar
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    
        customButtons: {
            // Add custom datepicker
            datepicker: {
                text: 'My datepicker',
                click: function(e) {
                    picker.show();
                }
            }
        },
        
        // Add the custom button to the header
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            right: 'datepicker today prev,next month'
        },
        plugins: ['timeGrid'],
        defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
    });

    calendar.render();

    // Initialize Pikaday
    var picker = new Pikaday({
        field: document.querySelector('.fc-datepicker-button'),
        format: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(dateString) {
            picker.gotoDate(new Date(dateString));
            calendar.gotoDate(new Date(dateString));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>

    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.3.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/pikaday@1.8.0/css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.3.1/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/moment@4.3.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.3.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/pikaday@1.8.0/pikaday.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```